# Create variable where I can reference its values by their position COBOL

Tags: image, variables, reference, cobol

First, let me thank you for taking your time to take a look at my question. 
I'm studying COBOL and I've been giving an exercise where I have to create a variable that has a number of cities from a country, I know how to create this with the hierarchy thing like:

```
01 COUNTRY.
 02 CITY-A PIC A(5) VALUE "TOKYO".
 02
 02
```

etc, etc.

The issue here is that I somehow need these values to be able to be referenced by their position. For example, I should be able to reference the CITY-A "TOKYO" by a number. Is there any way to do this? I just can't seem to figure this out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks again!

Comment: goodness, this takes me back, i suggest you look at the 'occurs' clause, which is used to declare 'arrays'. This may be useful: [2010/01/table-handling.html](http://www.mainframes360.com/2010/01/table-handling.html)

Comment: hey Ryan, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for,  I'll give it a try, thank you very much!!!

Comment: The more I read that article in the link, the less I like it. Generally you will get the point from there, but there are many errors and confusions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define your table of cities. Continuing in the style you have shown, here is an example with VALUE clauses.

```
01  CITY-TABLE.
    05  FILLER PIC X(30) VALUE "TOKYO".
    05  FILLER PIC X(30) VALUE "KYOTO".
    05  FILLER PIC X(30) VALUE "AIZUWAKMATSU".
    ... another 47 of these
```

Note that all the items must be the same length. "TOKYO" is five characters plus 25 trailing spaces. "AIZUWAKMATSU" is more characters, and fewer trailing spaces, but still 30 bytes. If you define your cities with fields of different lengths, you will not be able to reference them "by a number".

You will then need to use REDEFINES to give a different mapping of the data, in this case to give it a name which can be used for different occurrences in the table.

```
01  FILLER REDEFINES CITY-TABLE.
    05  CITY-NAME PIC X(30) OCCURS 50 TIMES.
```

With your data-structure defined, you can try using it.

```
MOVE "TOKYO" TO CITY-NAME
```

Actually, you can't do that. The compiler will not let you. There are 50 CITY-NAME elements, and the compiler requires that you tell it which one you want to use, any time you use CITY-NAME.

To access an element in a table, you need to use a subscript.

A subscript follows its data-name ("qualified" if necessary), and is enclosed in brackets/parentheses.

```
MOVE "TOKYO" TO CITY-NAME ( 1 )
```

Now that will compile. It is using a numeric integer literal as a subscript. Not useful in every case, as often we will be "looping" to use a table.

```
MOVE "TOKYO" TO CITY-NAME ( some-name )
```

Here `some-name` can be data defined by the programmer (as a numeric integer) or as an "index", a numeric integer which the compiler will manage.

To establish an "index", you code INDEXED BY some-name on the item containing the OCCURS clause.

If you use a data-name as a subscript, it is just a data-name, and you are largely unlimited with the COBOL Verbs you can use with it.

If you use an index-name (the INDEXED BY) you can only change the value of the index-name with SET, PERFORM and SEARCH.

```
PERFORM VARYING some-name FROM 1 BY 1 
   UNTIL input-byte ( some-name ) EQUAL TO SPACE
      OR some-name GREATER THAN 10
    ...
END-PERFORM
```

That is not such a good loop, but it is the sort of thing which will get you started.

Once complete, some-name will either be 11 (space not found) or it will be set to the value of the table which matched the first space in the data.

In the above PERFORM, some-name could either be an index-name or a data-name. The results will be the same, what the compiler generates will be different.

However, as a beginner, you should not need to be concerned with the differences between using a data-name as a subscript and using an index-name as a subscript. Your results will be the same, the generated code will be different. Leave it at that until you have some more experience.

You can have multi-dimensional tables. You can "offset" a subscript by a positive or negative amount. There is a hierachy of use for subscripts in the case of performance. There is a whole lot of understanding before you can accurately make use of "one being faster than another" (you can easily code the fastest access, and then loose much more than you save by doing the loop in a dumb way). There is also an index data item.

All of those things can be for later. Walk well first.

A final confusion (there are lots of confusions with subscripting) is there is reference-modification. Which looks a bit like using a subscript, but isn't, but can be used as a tortuous (from the point of view of later understanding) method of accessing a textual table.

```
MOVE "TOKYO" CITY-TABLE ( 1 : 30 )
```

Note that the table-name, rather than the entry-name, is being used. The colon (:) tells that it is reference-modification. Before the colon is the start-position, after the colon is the length. Both the start-position and the length can be data-names (but not index-names).

However,

```
MOVE CITY-TABLE ( VAR1 : 10 )
```

A typical sloppy usage of reference-modification, leaves the reader wondering what is being done with that data.

A subscripted item can be reference-modified, but again that is for later.

Comment: Very good and complete answer. Actually much better than the article link given in comments to the question.

Comment: @NealB thanks. If the link was any good, no need for the answer. I must have a word with the author about that when I remember. He's very keen, but not always thorough. Thanks for the edit.